# Need to convert a date 09/01/2009 to a CHAR TYPE FORMAT

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to convert a date 09/01/2009 to a CHAR TYPE FORMAT. The result should have 6 digits.

I knew the `TO_CHAR` function does it,but its not working for me.

The Date is given as 03/06/08

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(030608, 'DD MONTH,YYYY')
 FROM dual;
```

This gives errors-syntax mainly.

It is Oracle database and I have to get the `STRING`. For example a number like -'200901'

Comment: Do you mean you specifically have to convert '03/06/08' to 200806, or '09/01/2009' to 200901?

Comment: Why would you want to use a two-digit year?  Is 03/06/08 the equivalent of 6 March 1908 or 6 March 2008? If it's a date of birth, would that person visit a gerontologist or a pediatrician? Two-digit years were used in the 20th century, but ever since the y2k remediation era, almost all dates on all forms have become 4-digit.

Comment: Your question has the values '09/01/2009' (which may be a dd/mm/yyyy or a mm/dd/yyyy), '03/06/08' (which may be YY MM and DD in any order), '200901' (might be YYYYMM, YYMMDD or YYDDMM) and the format mask 'DD MONTH, YYYY' which doesn't correspond to ANY of the values in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SQL> -- Examples of the conversion functions.
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  d1    DATE;  
  d2    DATE; 
  d3    DATE;
  d4    DATE;
BEGIN
  d1 := TO_DATE('1/1/02','mm/dd/yy');      
  d2 := TO_DATE('1-1-1998','mm-dd-yyyy');
  d3 := TO_DATE('Jan 1, 2000','mon dd,yyyy');
  d4 := TO_DATE('1/1/02','mm/dd/rr');

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('d1 = ' || TO_CHAR(d1,'dd-Mon-yyyy'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('d2 = ' || TO_CHAR(d2,'mm/dd/yyyy'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('d3 = ' || TO_CHAR(d3,'Day, Month dd, yyyy'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('d4 = ' || TO_CHAR(d4,'Dy, Mon dd, yyyy'));

END;
```

Take the hint form this

Answer (score 1):

```
to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymm'); would return '201106'
```

Oracle's default format for DATE is "DD-MON-YY".  To convert a particular date, you could write

```
to_char('02-Jun-11', 'yyyymm'); should return '201106'
```

but better:

```
to_char(to_date('09/01/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'yyyymm'); should return '200901'
```

See http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve via the query mentioned, but you need to modify it to
this

```
select to_char(to_date('03062008','ddmmyyyy'),'yyyymm') from dual;
```

OR

```
select to_char(to_date('030608','ddmmyy'),'yyyymm') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Input      Desired output  How to get there
030608     '03/06/2008'    TO_CHAR(030608, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
'030608'   '03/06/2008'    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('030608', 'DDMMYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Share and enjoy.